# Cocoa NSTimer after sleep

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstimer, standby

In my Cocoa application I would like to get a callback  after N minutes, and I am using NSTimer to do so.

The problem however is that if the computer goes to sleep (or the time is set to a future time) and wakes after the timer should have fired, it will never fire.

What is the correct strategy to make sure I will get the callback after at least N minutes have passed?

Answer (score 0):

Use this method:

```
- (void)setFireDate:(NSDate *)date;
```

**EXAMPLE**

```
NSDate* fireDate= [[NSDate date] dateByAddingTimeInterval: N*60.0];
[timer setFireDate: fireDate];
```